# Changing model binding on Angular Formly based on expressionProperty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-formly

I'm using Angular Formly to build a form. I need the users to enter two email addresses(work and home). But if they are using the same address for both work and home they can simply click a checkbox which disables work email.

I've managed to hide the input box based on the checkbox using an Formly Expression.

```
expressionProperties: {
    hide: 'model.sameEmail'   
}
```

What I want to do is to set the model of the hidden email field to the one that is shown(It should keep updated as well).

Is this possible with Formly?

The sample plnkr is shown here: http://plnkr.co/edit/edlJaVIdo9z2j6Noyzqy?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a watcher in the checkbox to update the model:

```
watcher: {
  listener: function(field, newValue, oldValue, scope, stopWatching) {
    if (newValue) {
      scope.model.workEmail = scope.model.email;
    }
  }
}
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/TgCUfNCB4HhdUP7z93l1?p=preview

Mor info on watchers:

- http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/formly-expressions#watcher
- http://angular-formly.com/#/example/field-options/watchers

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the plnkr as well. It works as I expected.